# Autohotkey to change editor font?

Tags: autohotkey, text-editors

I've just downloaded [Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/), installed the 64-bit version, and start with the [tutorial](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Tutorial.htm).

How can I change editor font?

[image]

Comment: AHK comes with an editor?

Comment: Yeah it has one - updated my OP to show you the details.

Comment: Um, that screenshot says "AutoIt3".

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the zoom level in options, not sure about changing the font.

You can also use any other text editor if you like and use your editor of choice to change the font in that editor.  There is a tutorial available to set up Notepad++ with AHK syntax highlighting and whatnot but you don't need to do any of that to just edit a script in Notepad++ or Notepad or any other text editor.

You may also want to download and try [Scite4AutoHotkey](https://github.com/fincs/SciTE4AutoHotkey) instead of Scite-Lite

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file.
File extension - must be ".ahk".

".au3" - language file extension - AutoIt.

Scaling - [Ctrl] + [WeelUp / weelDown].

This font editor does not format the font of the script.
He is for creating code only.

How to change the font at the exit - I am looking for myself.
I know only for GUI.

; Font setting -% font%, size [s16], red, bold.
   font = Times New Roman
   Gui, Font, s10 cRed bold,% font%